# How can I easily iterate at the same time through rows and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `df` where if there is a numerical value in a cell, to return the value of the index and the column name:

```
             A  B  C 

 04/04/18   Nan Nan Nan
 05/04/19   Nan  4  Nan 
 06/04/20   Nan Nan  5
```

With the output:

```
["B-05/04/19","C-06/04/20"]
```

Is there any simple way I can iterate through rows and columns at the same time without the need of nested loops?

Comment: Are you looking for specific values or anything except NaN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If columns and index values are sorted use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and last join `MulitIndex` in list comprehension:

```
s = df.stack().dropna()
idx = ['{}-{}'.format(b, a) for a, b in s.index]
#python 3.6+
#idx = [f'{b}-{a}' for a, b in s.index]
print (idx)
['B-05/04/19', 'C-06/04/20']
```

Or get indices of non NaNs values, get values of indexing and join together:

```
x, y = np.where(df.notnull())
idx = df.columns[y] + '-' + df.index[x]
print (idx)
Index(['B-05/04/19', 'C-06/04/20'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Or `f'{b}-{a}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to jezrael's solution, but with `numpy.argwhere`:

```
>>> idx = np.argwhere(df.notna().values)                                                                                          
>>> ['{}-{}'.format(df.columns[j], df.index[i]) for i, j in idx]                                                                  
['B-05/04/19', 'C-06/04/20']
```